# Can't Figure out Why JSON / JSONP Isn't Working

Tags: php, json, jsonp

I have this PHP code:

JSON.php

```
<?php
    $array = array('items' => 38);
    $JSONItems = json_encode($array); 
    return $JSONItems;
?>
```

Items.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://domain.com/JSON.php?callback=?", 
        function(data){ alert(data.items) }
    );
</script>
```

When Items.html is displayed no alert is fired, and nothing happens.  (No Console Errors Or Anything)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: erm, don't you mean to `echo` from the PHP script?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `return` in your PHP script. That doesn't do what you think it does.

you need to use `echo`

Comment: I got it to work without the JSONP, but the moment I add the ?callback=? (for JSONP it doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

i just tried this and it works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/json.php", 
    function(data){ alert(data.items) }
);
 });
 </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$array = array('items' => 38);
$JSONItems = json_encode($array); 
 print_r( $JSONItems )  ;
?>
```

Comment: That's not going to help when the php script isn't outputting anything ;)

Comment: another good practice to use the JSON.stringify() function try to google it

Comment: What about when you add the ?callback=? (for JSONP) I can get it working in the format you listed above, but I can't get it working for JSONP